# For any $n\in N$ prove that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\varphi(d) = \prod_{p|n}(1 − p)$ where the product is taken over all prime divisors of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any $n \in N$ prove that $$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\varphi(d) = \prod_{p|n}(1 − p)$$ where the product is taken over all prime divisors of n.

I've tried to prove this using substitution of $$\varphi(n) = n\prod_{p|n} \left(1 −\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

and $\mu(n)=(-1)^m $ if $a_{1}= a_{2}=a_{3}=\cdots=a_{m}=1$

but I'm not sure this is the correct way to go about this problem

Comment: I think you mean $2-p$, not $1-p$.

Comment: No the question states 1-p

Comment: Then the question is wrong.  Try $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it's a multiplicative function.  What is it when $n$ is a prime power?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative hint:  Multiply out the right-hand side.  Then figure out why you don't need higher powers of the various $p$ on that side to match the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\phi(d)=\sum_{r=0}^m(-1)^r\text{ the product of distinct }r\text{ primes}$$

$$=\prod_{r=1}^m(1-p_r)$$